# Mathematical Complexity of Sparse Solvers

Tags: linear-solver, complexity

For a system $\mathbf{x=Da}$, there exist a lot of algorithms to estimate sparse vector $\mathbf{a}$.

I wish to know the big-O mathematical complexity of

1) orthogonal matching pursuit (OMP) both with fixed sparsity and error tolerance criteria.

2) L1-magic (which is based on interior point methods) algorithms.

Comment: Have you tried your own literature search first? Google gave as a first result for 1) the paper http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/131255/files/LocOMP.pdf For 2) some information can be found in http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.94.5220&rep=rep1&type=pdf, but complexity for iterative methods is a difficult issue because you'd need to estimate the number of iterations, which depends on a lot of factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This paper](http://dsp.rice.edu/sites/dsp.rice.edu/files/cs/FastL1.pdf) and [this one](http://ecovision.mit.edu/~sai/12S990/Yang10-SIAM.pdf) give a good overview of the complexity of different methods.

I find the feature sign search algorithm to be very fast, robust and useful. You could check it [here](http://ai.stanford.edu/~hllee/softwares/nips06-sparsecoding.htm), along with the paper :

> Efficient sparse coding algorithms
>
> Honglak Lee, Alexis Battle, Rajat Raina, and Andrew Y. Ng.
>
> NIPS 2006

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't answer the question at all (unless that paper contains a comparison of the complexity of their algorithm with the two the OP is asking about, in which case please include the relevant information in your answer).

Comment: You're right. Updated.

Comment: Thanks! Extra points for a) giving a full citation for these papers in case the links go away at some point and b) including the big-O complexities given in the paper in the answer as well.